# prove that: $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a_n+b_n) \le \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n) + \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} (b_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am reading Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis", and the following problem appears in it:

Problem 3.5:

> For any two real sequences $\{a_n\}$, $\{b_n\}$,
>
> prove that: $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} (a_n+b_n) \le \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n) + \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} (b_n)$
>
> provided the sum on the right is not of the form $\infty - \infty$

The solution in the manual goes as following:

> Since the case when $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n) = +\infty$ and $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(b_n) = -\infty$ has been excluded from consideration , we note that the inequality is obvious if $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n) = +\infty$. Hence we shall assume that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded above.
>
> Let $\{n_k\}$ be a subsequence of the positive integers such that $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(a_{n_k} + b_{n_k}) = \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n + b_n)$.
>
> Then choose a subsequence of the positive integers $\{k_m\}$ such that
>
> $$\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}(a_{n_{k_m}}) = \limsup_{k\rightarrow\infty}(a_{n_k})$$
>
> The subsequence $a_{n_{k_m}} + b_{n_{k_m}}$ still converges to the same limit as $a_{n_k} + b_{n_k}$.

And proof continue.
I understand all the proof except for the last sentence, precisely:

> The subsequence $a_{n_{k_m}} + b_{n_{k_m}}$ still converges to the same limit as $a_{n_k} + b_{n_k}$.

Why this is true?

I was thinking that we can also assume that $\{b_n\}$ also bounded so that it contains a series that converges and so $\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} (b_n)$ is finite but I don't know if this is useful and I couldn't go further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the answer from Kavi, and some extra effort I see that we can solve the problem as follows:

If $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(b_n) = +\infty$ then the inequality is also obvious so we can also (as we did with $\{a_n\}$) assume that $\{b_n\}$ is bounded.

Since both sequences are bounded, $\{a_n+b_n\}$ also bounded, and there is a subsequence of $\{a_n+b_n\}$ that converges so $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n+b_n)$ is finite and since:
$$\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(a_{n_k} + b_{n_k}) = \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}(a_n + b_n)$$

Then $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}(a_{n_k} + b_{n_k})$ is also finite and therefore converges.

Then every subsequence of it also converges to the same limit.

And this answers my question, but please correct me if there is a flaw somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If  a sequence converges (to a finite or infinite limit) then every subsequence of it also conveges to the same limit. This is immediate from the definition of limit.

Comment: Can we say that a sequence with an infinite limit converges?

I know the definition but I think that it is applicable when the limit is finite.

So if the supremum of a_n + b_n is infinite can we use it?

And what if every subsequence of a_n + b_n diverges but not into infinity? Then is the supremum defined here?

Comment: Rudin's proof is applicable even when $\lim \sup (a_n+b_n)$ is $\infty$. @KaisHasan

Comment: So every subsequence of a real-valued sequence that has an infinite or finite sum must have the same limit?
And what about other things that I mentioned in the previous comment.